# How many subsets of $A$ of $\{1,2,3,4\} $ are there that $(A\cup \{1,2\})-(A\cap \{1,2\})$ has exactly one point?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many subsets of $A$ of $\{1,2,3,4\} $ are there that $(A\cup \{1,2\})-(A\cap \{1,2\})$ has exactly one point?

I have solved it using brute force method by finding all subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ but  this way thing are becoming too difficult.

Is there are clever way to approach this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that that long expression is just $A\Delta\{1,2\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No. Let me look up the internet. Thanks for the head start

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So this is called symmetric difference of two sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$ (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) = (A \setminus (A\cap B)) \cup (B \setminus (A\cap B)) = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$$
So if you want it to have exactly one element, thera are two possibilities:

1. $A\setminus B = \varnothing$, and $B\setminus A$ has exactly one element. 
   $A \setminus B = \varnothing$ means $A\subset B$, and then the condition on $B\setminus A$ means that $A$ has exactly one fewer element than $B$. That means $A \in \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$
2. $B\setminus A = \varnothing$, and $A\setminus B$ has exactly one element. 
   $B \setminus A = \varnothing$ means $B\subset A$, and then the condition on $A\setminus B$ means that $A$ has exactly one more element than $B$. That means $A \in \{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\}\}$

In total $A\in \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\}\}$